# Using array and loop to update MySQL table

Tags: arrays, loops, mariadb

I have a table with 3 columns

```
pID | key_name   | value  
-----------------------
10 | 'series'   |'Songs'
10 | 'wood'     |'Beech' 
10 | 'language' |'German'
11 | 'series'   |'Songs'
11 | 'wood'     |'Oak'
11 | 'language' |'French'
12 | 'series'   |'Exams'
12 | 'language' |'English'
```

I need to update a table where the key_names are now column names, thus

```
pID | series | wood  | language
-----------------------------
10 ! 'Songs'|'Beech'|'German'
11 | 'Songs'|'Oak'  |'French'
12 | 'Exams'|       |'English'
```

Now I could write some SQL like

```sql
UPDATE dest-tbl INNER JOIN start-tbl
ON dest-tbl.pID = start-tbl.pID
SET dest-tbl.series = start-tbl.value
WHERE dest-tbl.key_name = 'series'
```

but since there are 65 different key_name values that would mean having to have 65 variations on that SQL.

It strikes me that the best way to do that might be to create an array of the key_name values and loop through that, except that I haven't go a clue how to do that.

Can anyone help me with this?

Using MariaDB v10.3

MTIA

---

**EDIT:**
I think I'm close to an answer with the SQL below.
I do need to insert this into another table and to filter the results based on the value of a field in another table. The code from SELECT down to GROUP creates the output I need but I've now got a problem with the JOIN part

```sql
INSERT INTO results ('series', 'wood', 'language')
SELECT table1.pID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'series' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'series',
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'wood' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'wood',
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'language' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'language'
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.pID
INNER JOIN ON table2.id = table1.pID
WHERE table2.id.type = 'product';
```

Comment: lok for pivot and dynamic sql

Comment: Would work if MySQL had a PIVOT function.

Comment: mysql has no pivot function, thatis why you need to build it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   t1.pID, 
   t1.value,
   t2.value,
   t3.value
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 on t2.pID=t1.pID and t2.key_name='wood'
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 on t3.pID=t1.pID and t3.key_name='language'
WHERE  t1.key_name='series';
```

output:

```
+ -------- + ---------- + ---------- + ---------- +
| 10       | Songs      | Beech      | German     |
| 11       | Songs      | Oak        | French     |
| 12       | Exams      |            | English    |
+ -------- + ---------- + ---------- + ---------- +
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2c122a1304a83f208113e336e3999b54)

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments to get a flexible solution you need dynamic sql

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `pID` INTEGER,
>   `key_name` VARCHAR(10),
>   `value` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`pID`, `key_name`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('10', 'series', 'Songs'),
>   ('10', 'wood', 'Beech'),
>   ('10', 'language', 'German'),
>   ('11', 'series', 'Songs'),
>   ('11', 'wood', 'Oak'),
>   ('11', 'language', 'French'),
>   ('12', 'series', 'Exams'),
>   ('12', 'language', 'English');
> ```

> ```
>     SET @sql = NULL;
>     SELECT
>       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'max(CASE WHEN `key_name` = ''',
>           `key_name`,
>           ''' THEN `value` ELSe "" END) AS `',
>           
>           `key_name`, '`'
>         )
>       ) INTO @sql
>       
>       FROM `tab1` ;
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `pID`, ',@sql,' from tab1
> GROUP BY `pID`');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> pID | language | series | wood 
> --: | :------- | :----- | :----
>  10 | German   | Songs  | Beech
>  11 | French   | Songs  | Oak  
>  12 | English  | Exams  |      
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da65abb383aad7effd4e50065cb0a678)*

Answer (score 0):

My solution, tested and working though a bit slow, is as follows:-

```
INSERT INTO results ('series', 'wood', 'language')
SELECT table1.pID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'series' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'series',
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'wood' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'wood',
MAX(CASE WHEN table1.meta_key = 'language' THEN table1.meta_value END) 'language'
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.ID=table1_pID AND table2.id.type = 'product';
GROUP BY table1.pID
```